# Dynamic change of content in tabs

Tags: php, jquery, html, dynamic, tabs

```
<?php --this is my index page--
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
  include ('Header.php');
  include ('Navigation.php');
  include ('Content.php');
  include ('Footer.php');
?>

<section class="tabs"> --this is my navigation tab--
  <ul class="links1lvl">
     <li class="active"><a>About</a>
        <ul class="links2lvl">
           <li class="active"><a href="../about/who.html">O nás</a></li>
```

I'm creating a new web and I need help with some coding. The idea is, that I have 2 sections. First for tabs to choose desired content and second as place to display actual content.

The thing is, I've found a ton of guides but those inlude the content of all tabs on that index page, but I have 20+ pages so that's unreal. What I desire is a page, where only the actual content would change as I click different tabs, without refreshing the whole page AND wich is loaded from ,,external" html/php files. Now I don't need code, I will gladly learn as much as I can on my own, thing I need however is a direction. Where should I look for solution.

Comment: Sorry the code was broken and wasn't showing, its fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use AJAX. This will allow you to trigger a call to an external file via Javascript, and display the result onto the current page without the need to refresh.

Comment: With the power of google I'm finding nice amount of results and it is exacly what I need, thank you very much. :)

Comment: No problem, good luck. To make your life easier i'd recommend using AJAX with jQuery.